# select from employee table where index is not in a collection

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure like below:

```
SET serveroutput ON 
    DECLARE 
        TYPE list_of_names_t 
          IS TABLE OF emp.emp_index%TYPE; 
        ignoreIndexes LIST_OF_NAMES_T := List_of_names_t();
    BEGIN
    -- Logic here which fills the values in the collection ignoreIndexes and           considerIndexes  
    -- Line XX   
END;
```

At Line XX, I want to add the below line

`SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp_index NOT IN ignoreIndexes` But not able to get the correct syntax, How to make that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the collection type is declared at the `schema level`, it can be used in `SQL statements` or dynamically .So do the following steps to make this work .

1. CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE list_of_names AS OBJECT(emp_index NUMBER);
2. CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE list_of_names_t IS TABLE OF list_of_names;
3. Create your anonymous block as shown below:

   ```
   SET serveroutput ON 
   DECLARE 
      ignoreIndexes LIST_OF_NAMES_T := List_of_names_t();
      emp_cur  SYS_REFCURSOR;
   BEGIN
      -- Populate the collection with some data
    SELECT list_of_names(LEVEL) 
        BULK COLLECT INTO ignoreIndexes  
    FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL<21;


   OPEN emp_cur FOR 
             SELECT * 
              FROM EMP e 
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                                    FROM   table(ignoreIndexes) tt 
                                    WHERE  tt.emp_index = e.emp_index
                                   );   

   END;
   ```